# ubuntu in virtual box in a macbook pro crashed during installation

Tags: virtualbox, system-installation, macbook

I have a mac book pro and I need to test ubuntu under virtual machine.

I have downloaded both xubuntu 13.10 64bit both ubuntu 12.04 64bit

I have downloaded Virtual box, created a new machine (with all default settings) and set the .iso file downloaded from the website (no dmg transformation, just plain .iso download) and.. ubuntu is crashing during the installation just after time zone setting and xubuntu crashes just before the installation..